# How to refactor nested Option.folds in Scala?

Tags: scala, refactoring

Suppose I am writing `foo:Int => Status` with given `f1: Int => Option[Int]` and `f2: Int => Option[Int]` as follows:

```
def f1(x: Int): Option[Int] = ???
def f2(y: Int): Option[Int] = ???

sealed trait Status
object Error1 extends Status
object Error2 extends Status
case class Ok(x:Int) extends Status

// probably not necessary
def error1: Status = Error1
def error2: Status = Error2
def ok(z: Int): Status = Ok(z)

def foo(x: Int): Status = f1(x).fold(error1){y => f2(y).fold(error2){z => ok(z)}}
```

IMO the nested `folds` look clumsy. How would you refactor it ?

Comment: `f1(x)(error1)` your `f1` is `Int => Option[Int]`, why the second parameter `error1`? This won't compile.

Comment: `foo` does not compile and doesn't use `fold` anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are into using `Either` you could do the following. It looks nicer, if it is understandable depends on how at ease you are with either.

```
val either = for {
  y <- f1(x).toRight(error1).right
  z <- f2(y).toRight(error2).right
} yield ok(z)

either.merge
```

Some background:

`Option.toRight` converts to a `Right` (success case) if the option is defined, otherwise returns a `Left` of the argument (error case).

`Either.right` projects the `Either` to the right, i.e. monadic operations are such that `Right` is `Some`, `Left` is `None`, but it preserves the `Left` value if we are in the left case.

`Either.merge` works only on `Either[A, A]` and returns whatever value is in the `Left` or the `Right`.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand `Either` and its projections (that are monads). Did not know about `toRight` and `merge`.